# How to make my images inline to the left of my component content?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an image with details about it such as a title. Could anyone inform my how to make it inline and to the left of the other content? An image is attached to explain what I'm trying to do.

[image]

```
return (
    <div key={obj.employee}>
        <p>{obj.employee}</p>
        <p>{obj.favDog}</p>
        <img alt={obj.favDog} src={obj.img} />
    </div>
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Using flex should help you. Here's a quick working example: https://jsfiddle.net/r1m4v659/ - hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just add `display: flex;` to your outer container, and everything should fall in to place nicely!**

[Here is a Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1m4v659/)

You can then add in margin, and the rest of your styles as you please.

If you want to learn more about flexbox, [this is an excellent reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). There's also the [MDN `flexbox` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

you can use **cssStyle** to send your picture to **left** side.

```
float:left;
margin:10px;
```

that is enough to make your picture inline.